# Stop Acrobat Pro from opening docs with expanded windows

Tags: pdf, ui

When I open a PDF file in Acrobat Pro DC (2015 Classic), it opens with a window the size of my 27" monitor. This is not very usable. I'd like to suppress this feature, which was not present on previous versions of Acrobat. Is there any way to disable it?

```
Architecture: x86_64
Build: 15.6.30174.187974
AGM: 4.30.64
CoolType: 5.14.5
JP2K: 1.2.2.36256
```

Comment: Does it open in full-screen mode or is it just a window that takes up the whole screen?

Comment: It's a window that takes up the whole screen. This is called an "expanded window." It what you get if you double-click the title bar in some apps. (It's what the green traffic light used to do before full-screen tablet-like mode). https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18785?locale=en_US

Comment: [This program on Github](https://github.com/jigish/slate) might help you resize the Acrobat windows automatically. The top 3 answers to [this similar question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124293/how-to-set-default-window-position-and-or-size) might help you as well.